# Mocking responses for GraphQL queries

Tags: vue.js, mocking, graphql, jestjs, vue-apollo

I'm developing a client application using Vue.js, jest for tests and Vue-apollo requesting to an external graphql endpoint.

My doubt is, how can I mock this server requests in my tests or in my application?

What would be the best approach, mock in tests or in application with fake data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Github issue: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/issues/244

What I do is mock mutate using `vue-test-utils` module and in case of queries check the `vm` if it has the correct `apollo` property structure and also set the state as if Apollo would. Then you can use snapshot testing to see if the template is rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [easygraphql](https://easygraphql.com/) to solve this challenge!! There are multiple packages that can be used:

1. [easygraphql-now](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-now/overview): you can create a script on your `package.json` that will run `"easygraphql-now schema.gql --graphiql --local -p=7000"` where you pass the schema route, local and graphiql flag, and the port... so when you run it; it will create a mocked server of the passed schema, so your application will make request to a server that will respond a mock of your query/mutation.
2. [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview): if you want to return a complete mock of the type, you can use this package, and with this, you don't have to create fixtures for each type.
3. [easygraphql-tester](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/overview): It's similar to [easygraphql-mock](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-mock/overview) but with the difference that you can return the mock of the query, check the [docs](https://easygraphql.com/docs/easygraphql-tester/usage#mocking-queries-and-mutations)